# My system restarts on pressing Windows key and mutes/unmutes on pressing Ctrl key

Tags: windows-xp, reboot, hotkeys, toolbar

Two days ago, I was trying to download software from http://download.cnet.com/

Cnet asked to install cnet toolbar and I thought that I wouldn't be able to download the software unless and until I installed the toolbar.

After installing the cnet toolbar I found that cnet has also installed Babylon toolbar on my Firefox and also its desktop application.

From that day my system is behaving weirdly.

1. PC shuts down if i press 'Windows' key
2. Sound mutes and unmutes itself every time i press 'cntrl' key..

Has anybody experienced anything like this?

Is it possible for third party to force hot keys?

Comment: The correct address for that site is http://download.cnet.com not `cnet.download.com`.  You may have inadvertently accessed a site that capitalized on the mixup to push malware.  I just tried to download something from the legitimate site, and it did not ask me about any toolbars.

Comment: dude... my urlis incorrect..but i knw the real cnet site..i just didn't copy paste it.. :P

Comment: Yes, but the fact is, I downloaded something 5 minutes ago, and I wasn't prompted for any toolbar.  Have you scanned for malware?

Comment: wait lemme search that link again..may be i will get some clue..

Comment: http://download.cnet.com/Technitium-MAC-Address-Changer/3000-2085_4-10554920.html its the link..original software is of 1.26MB but cnet makes u download the CNET installer and tool bar..for so called secure download..

Comment: Okay, I've gone there and clicked download now, and it downloads without any prompts.  I'm using Chrome, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: what is the size of the software? is it of 1.26MBs or  443 kbs?

Comment: @jonsca let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1043/discussion-between-sangram-and-jonsca)

Comment: I wrote up a brief answer and linked to the transcript of the chat

Comment: Yes, Jonsca. i wanted u to write the answer..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to beware of all of the options that the install programs have checked by default.  In this case, the toolbars being installed by one of these options, and were likely creating this mischief on the system.

Addendum: the user is going to get in contact via email to cnet and let them know that one of their prepackaged toolbars may not be on the level.

Comment: Transcript of chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1043

Comment: Btw..i scanned the pc with malware bytes, they were malwares but it problem still persists

Comment: @Sangram Hmm, well good that you found the malware.  Those present might be hiding others so don't give up hope yet.  [This](http://superuser.com/questions/100360) is a very comprehensive post about removing viruses and malware.